# Custom Audience Opt-Out Method

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ads

I'm working on some opt-out functionality and trying to use this endpoint:

https://graph.facebook.com/act_{ad_account_id}/usersofanyaudiences

from the docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/custom-audience-targeting/#opt-out

I've been using a POST with a single ID in the body, something like this: users=[{"id":"THIS_ID_HERE"}]

I keep getting the same error:

[Error: {"message":"Unknown path components: /usersofanyaudiences","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}]

Is a POST the right method to use? Something else I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies - looks like the documentation was out of date, the proper end point is https://graph.facebook.com/act_{ad_account_id}/usersofanyaudience (singular). We have updated the documentation.